# Can iPad and iPhone remember more Google account logins just like Android devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

On Android devices there seems to be unlimited Google accounts a user can log in and have the system memorize the user names and the passwords, so to log in automatically, it only takes one tap on the user name (which is an email address).

On iPhone and iPad, it seems that various apps using Safari to log in to Google and authorize the login. There is a 10 account limit, unlike Android devices. Is there any way to overcome this limit?

Comment: On iPhone and iPad, users are stored the same way they are on a computer. Because Android is made by Google it’s able to store the accounts differently.

Comment: Right, it is done on iPhone differently, and I am wondering if there is workaround or a hack to make it able to log in more as on Android